# How to get MySQL query to carry over with PHP Pagination?

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I am trying to keep my pagination based on the query I am using, but my problem is, it only works on the first page of pagination, and after that the query reverts to the standard one without filters (page one shows my filter, but page two show all results). I am wondering if there is an effective method that will carry over my filtered query when I click my pages, I am just at a loss right now as to how to accomplish this. Here is my code currently:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<style type="text/css">

#win-range, #gaa-range, #sv-range{
width: 160px;
font-size: 10px;
margin: 0 auto;     
}
#win-range a, #gaa-range a, #sv-range a{
margin-top: 0px !important;
padding: 0 !important;
}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
$(function(){

$("#win-range").slider({
range: true,
min: 1,
max: 1000,
values: [1, 1000],
slide: function(event, ui) {
    // in order to pass the user selected values to your app, we will use jQuery to prepopulate certain hidden form elements, then grab those values from the $_POST
    $("#minwins").val(ui.values[0]);
    $("#maxwins").val(ui.values[1]);
    $("#winamount").val(ui.values[0] + " - " + ui.values[1]);
}
});
$("#winamount").val($("#win-range").slider("values", 0) + " - " + $("#win-range").slider("values", 1));

});
$(function(){

$("#gaa-range").slider({
range: true,
min: 0,
max: 10,
values: [0, 10],
slide: function(event, ui) {
    // in order to pass the user selected values to your app, we will use jQuery to prepopulate certain hidden form elements, then grab those values from the $_POST
    $("#mingaa").val(ui.values[0]);
    $("#maxgaa").val(ui.values[1]);
    $("#gaaamount").val(ui.values[0] + " - " + ui.values[1]);
}
});
$("#gaaamount").val($("#gaa-range").slider("values", 0) + " - " + $("#gaa-range").slider("values", 1));

});
$(function(){

$("#sv-range").slider({
range: true,
min: 750,
max: 1000,
values: [750, 1000],
slide: function(event, ui) {
    // in order to pass the user selected values to your app, we will use jQuery to prepopulate certain hidden form elements, then grab those values from the $_POST
    $("#minsv").val(ui.values[0]);
    $("#maxsv").val(ui.values[1]);
    $("#svamount").val(ui.values[0] + " - " + ui.values[1]);
}
});
$("#svamount").val($("#sv-range").slider("values", 0) + " - " + $("#sv-range").slider("values", 1));

});
</script>

<?php 
include("includes/header.php");
include("includes/mysqli_connect.php");

$minwins = $_POST['minwins'];
$maxwins = $_POST['maxwins'];
$mingaa = $_POST['mingaa'];
$maxgaa = $_POST['maxgaa'];
$minsv = $_POST['minsv'];
$maxsv = $_POST['maxsv'];
$querySelection = $_POST['q'];
// FILTERING YOUR DB
$sortstats = $_GET['sortstats'];
$sortstatslow = $_GET['sortstatslow'];
// pagination
    $getcount = mysqli_query ($con,"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Player");
    $postnum = mysqli_result($getcount,0);// this needs a fix for MySQLi upgrade; see custom function below
    $limit = 6; //how many blog posts per page you will see.
    if($postnum > $limit){
    $tagend = round($postnum % $limit,0);
    $splits = round(($postnum - $tagend)/$limit,0);

    if($tagend == 0){
    $num_pages = $splits;
    }else{
    $num_pages = $splits + 1;
    }

    if(isset($_GET['pg'])){
    $pg = $_GET['pg'];
    }else{
    $pg = 1;
    }
    $startpos = ($pg*$limit)-$limit;
    $limstring = "LIMIT $startpos,$limit";
    }else{
    $limstring = "LIMIT 0,$limit";
    }

    // MySQLi upgrade: we need this for mysql_result() equivalent
    function mysqli_result($res, $row, $field=0) { 
        $res->data_seek($row); 
        $datarow = $res->fetch_array(); 
        return $datarow[$field]; 
    }


?>
<div class="listingcontainer">
<div class="sidebar">
    <h3>Sort By:</h3>
    <a href="listings.php?sortstats=Wins">Most Wins</a>
    <a href="listings.php?sortstatslow=GAA">Best Goals Against</a>
    <a href="listings.php?sortstats=SavePerc">Best Save %</a>
    <hr/>
    <h3>Custom Filter</h3>
    <br/>
    <div class="custom-filter">
        <form name="filters" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" id="filters">
            <label for="winamount">Win Range:</label>
            <input type="text" id="winamount" />
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            <input type="hidden" id="minwins" name="minwins" value="0" />
            <input type="hidden" id="maxwins" name="maxwins" value="1000" />
           <div id="win-range"></div>
           <br/>
           <label for="gaaamount">GAA:</label>
            <input type="text" id="gaaamount" /><br />
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            <input type="hidden" id="mingaa" name="mingaa" value="0" />
            <input type="hidden" id="maxgaa" name="maxgaa" value="10" />
           <div id="gaa-range"></div>
            <br/>
           <label for="svamount">SV %:</label>
            <input type="text" id="svamount" /><br />
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            <input type="hidden" id="minsv" name="minsv" value="750" />
            <input type="hidden" id="maxsv" name="maxsv" value="1000" />
           <div id="sv-range"></div>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"/>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="main-listings">
<h1>Current NHL Goaltenders</h1>
<?php 

    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Player ORDER BY PlayerID ASC $limstring");

    if(isset($sortstats)) {
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Player ORDER BY $sortstats DESC $limstring ") or die (mysql_error());
    }
    if(isset($sortstatslow)) {
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Player ORDER BY $sortstatslow ASC $limstring ") or die (mysql_error());
    }
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Player WHERE Wins BETWEEN '$minwins' AND '$maxwins' AND
                                                    GAA BETWEEN '$mingaa' AND '$maxgaa' AND  SavePerc BETWEEN '$minsv' AND '$maxsv'
                                                    ORDER BY PlayerID ASC $limstring") or die (mysql_error());
    }

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $name = $row['LastName'] . ", " . $row['FirstName'];
        $wins = $row['Wins'];
        $pid = $row['PlayerID'];
        $image = $row['Picture'];
        $gaa = $row['GAA'];
        $sv = $row['SavePerc'];
        echo "<div class=\"player-listing\">";
        echo "<div class=\"image-holder\">";
        echo "<span class=\"helper\"></span>";
        echo "<a href=\"viewplayer.php?playerId=$pid\"><img src=\"admin/thumbs/$image\" alt=\"$name\"></a>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<div style=\"clear:both;\"></div>";
        echo "<a href=\"viewplayer.php?playerId=$pid\">$name</a>";
        echo "<table align=\"center\">";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td style=\"border-bottom: 1px solid #212121;\">Wins</td>";
        echo "<td style=\"border-bottom: 1px solid #212121;\">GAA</td>";
        echo "<td style=\"border-bottom: 1px solid #212121;\">SV%</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>$wins</td>";
        echo "<td>$gaa</td>";
        echo "<td>.$sv</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>";
        echo "</div>";
    }

    // paging links:
    echo "<div class=\"paging\">";
    if($postnum > $limit){
        echo "<span class=\"page-numbers\"><strong>Pages:</strong> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>";
        $n = $pg + 1;
        $p = $pg - 1;
        $thisroot = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
        if($pg > 1){
            echo "<a href=\"$thisroot?pg=$p\"><< prev</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        }
        for($i=1; $i<=$num_pages; $i++){
            if($i!= $pg){
                echo "<a href=\"$thisroot?pg=$i\">$i</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            }else{
                echo "$i&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            }
        }
        if($pg < $num_pages){
            // INSERT QUERY STRING VARIBLE TO CARRY OVER DB QUERY
            echo "<a href=\"$thisroot?pg=$n\">next >></a>";
        }
        echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    }
    // end paging
    echo "</div>";
?>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Comment: I've gotten everything to work with the use of sessions and setting a custom string filter for each session. My problem is, if there are few results that don't meet the limit per page, I still get paging links on the bottom, and when they're clicked they show more results that aren't relevant to my filter. Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save you search filters in session and always check the session value is set for any search or not and pass that data into you query.until and unless nobody reset that search criteria and when your user reset that search criteria to null then put the value blank in the session for that **session search variable.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass all filter conditions to the paginating link, for example

```
    $filter = "minwins={$minwins}&maxwins={$maxwins}&mingaa={$mingaa}&minsv={$minsv}&maxsv={$maxsv}&q={$querySelection}";
    if($pg > 1){
        echo "<a href=\"$thisroot?pg=$p&$filter\"><< prev</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    }
    for($i=1; $i<=$num_pages; $i++){
        if($i!= $pg){
            echo "<a href=\"$thisroot?pg=$i&$filter\">$i</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        }else{
            echo "$i&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        }
    }
    if($pg < $num_pages){
        // INSERT QUERY STRING VARIBLE TO CARRY OVER DB QUERY
        echo "<a href=\"$thisroot?pg=$n&$filter\">next >></a>";
    }
```

In the code for getting filter conditions from $_POST you are using, change it to $_REQUEST because it should get from URL ($_GET).

Ex

```
$minwins = $_REQUEST['minwins'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the below to create a list of URL keys (filters).

```
foreach($_GET as $key => $value){
  $url_keys .= $key . "=" . $value . "&";
}
```

And then add that into your URL for next/prev page.

```
echo "<a href=\"$thisroot?pg=$n&$url_keys\">next >></a>";
```

You will then be passing your filters through the URL and have access to them on the next page.